# Proper use of wildcards and the PECS principle in Java Stream operations

Tags: java, generics

I'm working with Java Streams and trying to understand the proper use of wildcards, especially in the context of the PECS (Producer extends, Consumer super) principle. I've come across situations where I'm not entirely sure of the best practices.

Consider the following code:

```java
Predicate<Object> isPositive = n -> (Integer) n > 0;
Stream.of(-2, 5, 8).filter(isPositive);
```

I believe my Stream works as supplier, any method which takes should have parameter of <? extends T> as per PECS.

Shouldn't we use an upper-bound wildcard (<? extends T>) for the Predicate in this case to allow more type-specific predicates like Predicate to be used? Or is there a reason to use a lower-bound wildcard (<? super T>) here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The stream might act as a supplier, but the Predicate is a consumer.

Comment: "Shouldn't we use an upper-bound wildcard (`<? extends T>`) for the Predicate in this case" Why? The predicate is not a producer of a `T`, is it? It takes (consumes) a `T` and produces a `boolean` telling you whether the `T` satisfied a condition.

Comment: In this case, it would not compile because `filter` expects an argument of type `Predicate<? extends Integer>` and `Predicate<? extends Integer>` doesn't match another `Predicate<? extends Integer>`. `Predicate<Integer> isPositive = n -> n > 0;` works fine though.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for clarification. My previous understanding was Producer and Supplier are only a collection. Now I am clear Producer is anything that produces T and consumers is that consumes T.